# AngularJS serving up *partially* old code on localhost

Tags: angularjs, variables, scope, osx-elcapitan

So this is weird...I have a $scope variable in my controller assigned to a string.

I have since changed that string.

It is serving up the *original* string that is long gone.

I know, I know: clear your browser cache. Did that. It's still there. I tried Firefox and Safari. You know what? I didn't have Opera installed, so I downloaded and installed Opera, and the old string even showed up in Opera, which my computer -- a 2015 MacBook Pro running the latest version of OSX El Capitan.

I know, I know: flush the Apache cache, even though it's disabled on a Mac and I never enabled it. Fine. I ran htcacheclean -r -p on the directory in the code, and I'm still getting the old code.

I know, I know: make sure you didn't accidentally point to the wrong directory. Uhmm....thing is, there's only *one copy* of this code on the entire drive. Plus, even though the new $scope variable source code changes are being ignored, I can make changes to the functions in the exact same file but it's definitely honoring *those* changes.

For the record, here's the code that's not changing:

```
$scope.credits = '<div class="credits" id="show_cred">';
$scope.credits += '<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="up">';
```

When I load up the page, it's showing that the string is:

```
<div class="credits">
```

And that's it. No ID. No "marquee." (And yes, I do have the corresponding closing tags later in the string, and they do get rendered...well, except the closing "marquee" tag because, well, that's a new line that it's refusing to acknowledge.) I went so far as to change that entire $scope.credits variable to be nothing but this:

```
$scope.credits = '';
```

....but the old variable still renders.

I tried merging those two lines into a single line, but nope.

In the same controller file -- again, the same file -- it actually does reflect modifications I make to functions, but not variables.

This...is the most bizarre situation I've seen in all my years as a web dev. This is definitely not browser-based. It's definitely not Apache's cache (unless I'm lied to and that it *is* enabled on a Mac and that the htcacheclean command is a placebo).

What do you all make of this?

Comment: I've got the exact same problem and I haven't found any solutions. I've also tried to clear caches, reboot, restart system, restart browser, install another browsers and so on. The only "solution" is to get rid of AngularJS, I think, and try to switch to another framework, like Ember.js, Backbone.js or React.

Comment: Are you sure that you were referencing the content of $scope.credits and the HTML was not being set from somewhere else? If you can share the view and controller code showing the issue it might be easier for others to help find the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did come up with a solution, and it's something I should have done from the beginning.

Instead of having a buttload of HTML assigned to a scope variable, I put it in the view itself and attached it to an ng-if directive. That fixed my problem in that the site now does what I intended it to do.

However, it doesn't actually answer the question as to how in the world the variable's old value was set in stone.